# Codeblocks issue with consoles and debugging

Tags: gdb, g++, codeblocks, xterm, gnome-terminal

I am running `Codeblocks 13.12` installed from the official ubuntu repos (I am running `LinuxMint 18` on `4.4.0-34-generic` kernel).
Whenever I have XTerm as my terminal on `C::B` (`Settings->Environment->Terminal` to launch console programs:`xterm -T $TITLE -e`), the debugging works flawlessly.

But when I select gnome-terminal as my "running" terminal, magically the debugging stops working. I do not know if it is a bug or if the `gnome-terminal` has some issues or even if codeblocks doesn't like `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Please don't ask SO members to "respond ASAP". It's rude.We are volunteering our free time.

Comment: In any case, gnome-terminal is well-known to have an incompatible `-e` option (and it is off-topic).

Comment: sorry for the ASAP, btw i'll just use xterm